# Select only unique values

Tags: sql-server, select

Tabls is

```
ID  Count
1    30
2    30
3    10
4    15
5    10
6    25
```

I want query which will give me

```
4    15
6    25
```

in result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ID,  Count
FROM dbo.TableName t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
   WHERE t1.ID <> t2.ID AND t1.Count = t2.Count
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77a6a/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: Please note that here also you should have an index on `Count`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: mentioned that an index would be helpful. However, imho that depends on if this query is used only once or often and how large the table is at all.

Comment: I mentioned it in my answer - who knows whether it's being read :-) Yes, it's a matter of how often this is done, but can it hurt to do it any case?

Comment: Thanks, Tim, I know that - but it's a simple table with probably the PK being on ID. I know that many indices with many columns slow things down significantly, but here I guess it speeds up lookup more than it slows down inserts.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: sorry, i've just deleted my link-only comment. For the sake of completeness, it was this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/764217/284240 My point is, if i would add an index on every column that i need to query somewhere i would have to add an index on everything.

Comment: Well, if you already have an index that restricts the number of rows significantly before doing the "unindexed search" I agree, but here it comes down to a full table scan without an index - and full table scans are hardly ever desired...

Answer (score 1):

The following should select what you want:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.[Count] 
FROM Table t 
WHERE 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table t1 WHERE t1.[Count] = t.[Count]) = 1
```

Please note that you should really have an index on `Table.[Count]`.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do it with a grouping statement

```
SELECT MIN(ID), Count
FROM Table
GROUP BY Count
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HAVING together with COUNT DISTINCT, to limit the result:

```
SELECT [Id], [Count]
FROM MyTable
WHERE [Count] IN (
    SELECT [Count]
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY [Count]
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Count]) = 1
)
```